# Is this possible - Python script to fill a Google spreadsheet?

Tags: python, google-sheets

I dont even know if this is possible. But if it is, can someone give me the broadstrokes on how I can use a Python script to populate a Google spreadsheet?

I want to scrape data from a web site and dump it into a google spreadsheet. I can imagine what the Python looks like (scrapy, etc). But does the language support writing to Google Drive? Can I kick off the script within the spreadsheet itself or would it have to run outside of it?

Ideal scenario would be to open a google spreadsheet, click on a button, Python script executes and data is filled in said spreadsheet.

Comment: Can't python consume their API? Sorry, I'm new to Python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google GData (library with interfaces for all Google services) Python client:

https://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/

Spreadsheets API docs (linked from previous page):

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/?csw=1

Answer (score 1):

The question is from 2013. But still, as I was interested today by the answer, I though it could help some other people :

Google developed GScript, equivalent of VBA from Microsoft. I guess with this language you can easily scrape web data and include them into the sheet.

Otherwise, if you want to use Python, here is a great tutorial explaning how to use Google API v4:

https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python

The missing step: launching python script directly from the google sheet.

I hope it helps !

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible and this is how I am personally doing it so.

search for "doGet" and "doPost(e)